# Single sign on using WIF (.Net 4.5) combined with java application

Tags: java, asp.net, wif

I need some help in what to use to achieve a SSO-application containing 2 web applications and I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Let say that the  first web application is running on asp.net 4.5 and the second one is running on a java plattform. My first thought was to run WIF (passive federated identity). I have read a lot of articles regarding WIF but havent found any when using 2 types of program language but haveing the same (customer domain i.e customer repository).

Is it a good idea to use Windows Identity Foundation(?) i.e is there a way for a java plattform to use/read claims and auth tokens generated by WIF (passive federated identity)?

If yes can you share any documentation/example how I will achieve this?

If no is there an alternative? I cant use openId/openauth etc because of policies etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIF is only for .NET.

Have a look at [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) and the links in that article. There are some Java WIF equivalents.

Or you could use a Java SAML library like OpenSAML - link in the article above - and go SAML to ADFS rater than WS Federation.

Or use something like OpenAM for the Java application and federate with ADFS.